# How do you define a set of all numbers with $N$-length decimal expansions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

That is to mean a set of all numbers with $0,1,2,\dots,N$ decimal places. If I was going to generate the set I would just use a step of the $N$th unit, so if $N = 5$ then my step would be $0.00001$.

What is the formal Set Theory construction of such a set?

Comment: Do you just mean $S_n=\{10^{-n}k:k\in \mathbb Z\}$ ?

Comment: In fact, sometimes that set is simply denoted $10^{-n} \Bbb Z$.

Comment: To get a "formal Set Theory" statement we need to know which theory. Are you asking for a set in the real numbers, rationals, complex, or other? And which formalization of that set are you using? The natural numbers have been fairly standardized, but the others not so much.

Comment: Thanks @MPW, that's what I was looking for. If you write that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want $$S_n=\{10^{-n}k:k\in \mathbb Z\}$$